# How to include folder excluded by parent .gitignore?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have two projects that have separate .gitignore files.

So, the project structure is as:

```
child-project-
             |
             images
             .gitignore
main-project-
            |
            some source code
images-
.gitignore
```

Now in the parent .gitignore I have a line such as `images/` which excludes the directory called `images` that is located in the parent. But, I have another folder called `images` that is located inside the `child-project` directory, and I want it to be included. How can I enable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only ignore `images/` in the top level directory, use

```
/images/
```

in the topmost `.gitignore`.

From the `git help ignore`:

> A leading slash matches the beginning of the pathname. For example, `/*.c` matches
>              `cat-file.c` but not `mozilla-sha1/sha1.c`.

Answer (score 2):

Use negations:

Directory structure:

```
.
├ .gitignore
├── child-project
│   ├── .gitignore
│   ├── build
│   │   └── build.zip
│   └── images
│       └── image.png
├── images
│   └── image.ong
└── main-project
```

Root *.gitignore*:

```
images
```

Child *.gitignore*:

```
build
!images
```

Now it will see `child-project`:

```
git st 
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        child-project/images/
```

You can also tune you root `.gitignore` to exclude only specific `images` directories, like

```
/images
/path/to/other/project/images
```

But this will require you to list all those directories.